# Why can't I write down tilde? Is there any MathJax syntax?

Tags: support, mathjax

In [an answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/695534/315444), I wanted to write `∼`, but that wasn’t showing. I think it wasn’t showing for Markdown.

So I thought I should use `\tilde`, but it came on top of the next letter. How can I write down tilde in MathJax?

Comment: Related: *[MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020)*. Tilde is [somewhat covered](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference/13081#13081) (but not for this(?)).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`∼` is a small space, while `\tilde{}` is an ornament of a character. Use instead e.g. `\sim`. More generally, for such LaTeX questions, check out [Detexify](https://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html).

Comment: Minor note: if the spacings don't look right, use `{\sim}`. The bare `\sim` is a binary operator and is spaced accordingly, which might be too much space for several common applications.

Comment: $\uparrow$ Good point.